# Postfix "unknown user" using dovecot-lda and no unix account

Tags: postfix, dovecot

Historically I've had a local user account for each email user and everything has been fine. Recently I've moved from Procmail to dovecot-lda, with Dovecot using its own user database.

Dovecot is quite happy to deliver mail, and let users collect it, without needing local user accounts. As such I've looked at trying to remove the local users and instead set dovecot to use a generic `vmail` user. TO test I've set the correct mail path for my test user in the Dovecot user database, but set the UID to be my vmail user and changed the ownership of the relevant mail folders to vmail.

This works fine for imap/pop connections, and manually running the dovecot-lda works fine. As far as I can see the entire delivery and collection process works fine as far as Dovecot is concerned.

However, If I try and deliver an email via Postfix, I get the following message:

```
status=bounced (unknown user: "test-user")
```

I thought this would be as simple as un-setting `local_recipient_maps` to stop Postfix trying to validate local users, but I just can't seem to get past this error. Is there some simple option I'm missing to make Postfix ignore the fact that a local user doesn't exist and just pass the message to dovecot?

Applicable Postfix config

```
mailbox_command = /usr/local/libexec/dovecot/dovecot-lda -f "$SENDER" -a "$RECIPIENT" -d "$USER"
local_recipient_maps =

virtual_alias_domains = $config_directory/local-host-names
virtual_alias_maps = hash:$config_directory/virtusertable
```

There's an entry in `virtusertable` for my test email address with `test-user` as the right hand side.